# What kind of stochastic process is this (in a discrete event queuing simulation)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have got a discrete event queuing simulation with a randomized input.

On every time unit a new customer comes in with a probability of 0.4. The customer demands 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 or 10 products.

What kind of stochastic process is this? And what are the mathematical expressions related to this problem?

Comment: It seems that you are rather describing a stochastic process rather then distribution.

Comment: Hi Tim, you are right. I edited it.

Comment: my guess: a discrete time version of an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/G/1_queue  sorry that I can't help much more